# Orthogonal groups over finite fields

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

I was searching for orthogonal groups over finite fields, but in the google search I was getting only orthogonal groups over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and similarly in google books.

> Can anyone suggest some good exposition of orthogonal  groups over finite fields from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that this is not an easy topic, and it is very technical. Odd and even characteristics are different, and even dimension is different from odd dimension. In general, in even dimensions, there are two isomorphism types of these groups, plus and minus types, but in odd dimension there is just one. In odd characteristic, you can define them, as in the real and complex cases, as the groups preserving symmetric bilinear forms, but in characteristic $2$ you have to define them as the groups preserving quadratic forms, in order to distinguish them from the symplectic groups.

Probably the best source is Emil Artin's book Geometric Algebra, dating from about 1953. For experts who just want to learn about their definitions and basic properties as quickly as possible, Chapter 2 of the book "The Subgroup Structure of the Finite Classical Groups" by Kleidman and Liebeck is a good source, but that might not be the right one for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I will follow at least these books now!